# Jailbreak iOS 11.4 full version

Tags: ios, jailbreak

Is there any full jailbreak for iOS 11.4 except Electra (it's for 11.2 — I cannot downgrade cause Apple doesn't sign that firmware anymore)? Because, honestly I think that Pangu Anzuchang is not a full feature jailbreak as it's just a web clip application which does not inject a kernel exploit (as Electra does, that's why it restarts the device), so what will you suggest?

### UPDATE

iOS 11.4 is a stable release now. Any jailbreak methods are available?

Comment: @Scottmeup  This question was asked earlier, please check the dates carefully

Comment: I'll defer to the moderators in this case. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS 11.4 is currently in beta and isn't released publicly yet. It is not possible get Jailbreak for an unreleased iOS version.

iOS beta releases are highly susceptible to change, hence you can never find a Jailbreak for them.

Comment: I go to check my device info, and it says: iOS 11.4 (without public beta or anything), is it a PB1?

Comment: It could be either developer or public beta. The latest is beta 4 released four days ago.

Answer (score 1):

Re update: no.

iOS versions are not usually jailbroken while still signed by Apple.

Future note for your update when 11.4 goes unsigned: Probably still no. Even if a vulnerability is discovered it takes time to develop that into a working jailbreak.