# 11.4 Full Jaillbreak method Yet?

Tags: ios, jailbreak

I've been searching around for a a while now and So far I haven't found any full jailbreaks for ios 11.4 on a 6s. To be honest, I am new to the jailbreaking scene. I've installed Velonzy, but could find no jailbreaking tools. Am I missing something, or is there truly nothing left.

PS. I would downgrade to a system-rootable version but I haven't any SHSH blobs, or found any alternative method. Is it possible?

Comment: You might be able to install a beta version of 11.3.x, but I have no idea if that's going to cause any future problems, what with it being a beta. The jailbreak subreddit is probably a better source of info for all things JB related.

Comment: If you want a jailbreak, downgrade to iOS 11.3b6 while you still can.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jailbreak iOS 11.4 full version](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/324516/jailbreak-ios-11-4-full-version)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I jailbreak?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/336229/how-do-i-jailbreak)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing for 11.4 has been announced. Very rarely is a currently-signed iOS version jailbreakable.

Save your blobs for every signed version of iOS you can while it's still being signed, and stick on the lowest version of iOS is the recommended advice if you hope to jailbreak.

Just be aware that failure to update to the latest version of iOS may result in your device being less than secure as it could be. Often it's the insecurities that are leveraged into a jailbreak, so the choice is up to you.